# Load XML containing no namespace

Tags: xml, namespaces

I am very new to xml. I have this xml file, which I'm trying to load and edit in my code, but throws some error. As I am new to xml, I tried to do basic research but failed. Can someone please help me.
the xml code is as follows:

```
<SLM:stylesheet>
<SLM:system>
    <SLM:module name="Category-A">
        <SLM:member state="stateless">a1</SLM:member>
        <SLM:member state="stateless">a2</SLM:member>
        <SLM:member state="stateless">a3</SLM:member>
        <SLM:member state="stateless">a4</SLM:member>
        <SLM:member state="stateless">a5</SLM:member>
        <SLM:member state="stateless">a6</SLM:member>
    </SLM:module>
</SLM:system>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance to all the helpers.

Comment: Did you close the tag with </SLM:stylesheet> at the end ?

Comment: as mentioned SLM:stylesheet is opened but not closed. In addition, I think it would be better if you use something like: SLMstylesheet, SLMsystem, SLMmodule rather than using the Colon in the middle

Comment: Yes I have, its not about the tags, Namespace not defined is the error I'm getting.

Comment: try removing the colon ':", instead of "SLM:stylesheet" use "SLMstylesheet"

Comment: An error has been found! 
Errors in the XML document: 
 2: 13 The prefix "SLM" for element "SLM:system" is not bound.

Comment: error on line 2 at column 12: Namespace prefix SLM on system is not defined
error on line 5 at column 34: Namespace prefix SLM on module is not defined
error on line 6 at column 38: Namespace prefix SLM on member is not defined
error on line 15 at column 34: Namespace prefix SLM on module is not defined
error on line 16 at column 38: Namespace prefix SLM on member is not defined
error on line 27 at column 36: Namespace prefix SLM on component is not defined
error on line 28 at column 21: Namespace prefix SLM on command is not defined

These are the errors I'm getting

Answer (score 0):

Technically your file is well-formed according to the XML recommendation, but it is not namespace-well-formed according to the XML namespaces recommendation (because there is no namespace declaration for the SLM prefix). These days nearly all parsers require the file to be namespace-well-formed, and the error messages are telling you that this one is not.